# Malware affected my wordpress sites

Tags: wordpress, popup, malware

All of my wordpress sites are affected with a pop up malware. Wherever clicks it will go to another ad page. Please some one help help . website name www.farusia.com .I have tried several anti malware plugins but all are paid service.

Comment: What have you tried, error messages, research, ...

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be stemming from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.pub2srv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1063894"></script>
```

This is most likely somewhere in your themes function.php or index.php